# syntax error, unexpected '$config' (T_VARIABLE) in Silverstripe

Tags: php

I have create a class GalleryImage In SilverStripe.In that I am creating a config object for the grid field, but it gives error syntax error, unexpected '$config' (T_VARIABLE). How to solve this ?

```
    $config = GridFieldConfig::create();
```

Comment: Please give the code so that we can give the solution.

Comment: -1 for "Please give me solution."  Give us the code, and we'll answer questions about what is confusing you.  You need to put effort into understanding what's going on yourself.

Comment: better read [*this*](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Chances are the problem is on the line (or lines) before. For example this:

```
$myvar=1;
$config = GridFieldConfig::create();
```

won't cause a syntax error (of the type you're seeing here) but:

```
$myvar=1
$config = GridFieldConfig::create();
```

(note the missing semi-colon) will cause an error like you are getting.

It may not be a missing semi-colon, but check the line *before* the one giving you the error.

Comment: Guarantee you it's a missing semicolon.  Then again, they could be really screwing up the class definition.